# How can I produce a summary report for one or more projects in CiviVolunteer?

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

We have implemented CiviVolunteer to manage our 30 projects across 118 volunteers.

The positives:

Projects are linked via Activities in sympathy with the overall CiviCRM design philosophy.

Once two bug fixes were applied, it now works as specified - all good.

The negatives:

The Volunteer subclass of Individual has popped up but is not used by CiviVolunteer for the actual volunteers. This is a bit confusing and instructions in our User Guide (thank you Echo Plugins for Knowledge Base for Documents and FAQs) are the way that we have dealt with this.

The Volunteer reports don't expose the two relationships (Owner or Manager).

The overall reporting system of CiviCRM doesn't appear to support (out of the box) summarisation of rows (e.g. a count of rows, a sum of values from a row, etc.).

Sounds like a lot of negatives, but we are using CiviVolunteer and are achieving a deal of acceptance from our users.

As requested in the guidelines, that's our story.

The question is, how can I produce a report with fields: Project Name, Manager Name, Owner Name, and Number of Volunteers?

Regards,

Rob.

Comment: Hey Rob - what CMS are you using - ah see on your other Q's you have WP so my saying "if Drupal then may be worth becoming familiar with Views which can, in our experience, get around a lot of limitations in civi Reports" is of no use to you unless it saves you so much pain that it is worth wiring in Drupal (as well as WP) to your civi install so you can use both Views and Webforms to bend the laws of the civi universe

Comment: Thx petednz, We are committed to WP as our Mkt/Comms lady is adept, but I will keep it in mind as an alternative if no other light shines over the horizon.